# Would questions about how to teach a specific topic of graphic design be too broad?

Tags: discussion

For example, I was discussing with a colleague about teaching how to better observe. He had a teacher who had the following assignment:

She brought a pile of oranges in class, each student picked one and had to draw it as detailed as possible, then bring all of them back into a pile. Pile got all mixed and the plot twist is that the teacher requested every student to find their orange again. They then used their drawing to see if they had the right one.

That is obviously one of many, many potential answers and it might not work with everyone, but I think it might be useful knowledge for educators and exercices for novices. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on how you word the question. We've had a few questions over the years on how to teach a topic that remain open so there's nothing inherently off-topic about them IMO (of course member opinion changes). If you word it well though I think it'll be fine.